# LINQ Join query problem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have this query that I tried to join 2 tables together, one which holds the product name, and product numbers, and take a product number, and go to the other where to find a Art_no which is like the product number.

```
ProductNamesList = (From ProductSeries In context.Products
                             From ProductRevisions In context.TestResults
                             Where ((ProductSeries.Product = CurrentProduct) And (ProductRevisions.Art_no.Contains(ProductSeries.Product_no)))
                             Order By ProductRevisions.Art_no
                             Select ProductRevisions.Art_no).Distinct.ToList
```

Hope anyone can help,
Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to return any values

Comment: For some reason, it started to work O.o thats odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the post : [SQL to LINQ ( Case 7 - Filter data by using IN and NOT IN clause)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-case-7-filter-data-by-using_15.html)

you solution is divided into two queries as below

```
//first get the list of product which satisfy your condition

    var ids = (from p in context.Products
              Where p.Product = CurrentProduct
              select p.Product_no).ToList();

//second filter the revision products by using contains

    var myProducts = from p in context.TestResults
                     where ids.Contains(p.Art_no)
                     Order By p.Art_no
                     Select p.Art_no;
```

Comment: The ProductSeries.Product_no is LIKE ProductRevisions.Art_no, they don't equal

Comment: I was doing it with 2 queries, trying to get it with 1 query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following class structure:

```
public class Context
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TestResult> TestResults { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestResult
{
    public int ArtNo { get; set; }
}
```

And an instance of context:

```
var context = new Context
                {
                    Products = new List<Product>
                                {
                                    new Product {Id = 1, Name = "P1"}, 
                                    new Product {Id = 2, Name = "P2"},
                                },
                    TestResults = new List<TestResult>
                                {
                                    new TestResult {ArtNo = 1},
                                    new TestResult {ArtNo = 2}
                                }
                };
var currentProduct = context.Products.ElementAt(0);
```

This should return what you expect:

```
var query = from product in context.Products
            from testResult in context.TestResults
            where product.Id == testResult.ArtNo
            && currentProduct == product
            orderby testResult.ArtNo
            select product.Name;

// Returns a list with one item "P1"
var productNames = query.Distinct().ToList();
```